# How to remove text from Google Docs using App Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I just recently built a series of documents using Google Script and Form/Sheets.

The document generates in Google Docs via the script, using the data provided in the initial form.

The setup is basically as below:

### Conditions to pass

- Class: {{CLASS}}
- Minimum Grade: {{MINIMUM_GRADE}} / 10
- Minimum attendance: {{ATTENDANCE_PERC}}% with a minimum of {{ATTENDANCE}} attendances over the semester

Where the form input is placed between those {{ }}.

**Currently**, this case would show something like:

- Class: 3rd Year
- Minimum Grade: Not Applicable / 10
- Minimum attendance: 70% with a minimum of 15 attendances over the semester

But I would like:

- Class: 3rd Year
- Minimum attendance: 70% with a minimum of 15 attendances over the semester

Is there any way that I can make Google Script automatically remove, any of the the bullet point, for example here "Minimum Grade" if the answer to this question is "Not Applicable"?

Comment: Can you share the code which populates the Document file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can get all children of the Document, and remove the child from the body if the Element object is a `LIST_ITEM`* ***and*** *the Element object contains the text "Not Applicable".*

#### More Information:

The structure of a Document is quite tricky, but knowing that a given child is a `LIST_ITEM` Element type, you can check to see if it contains the text you require and subsequently remove the child from the body of the Document.

#### Code:

```
function removeListItem() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var noOfChildren = body.getNumChildren();
  var childrenToRemove = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < noOfChildren; i++) {
    var child = body.getChild(i);
    var childType = child.getType();
    if (childType == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) {
      if (child.asListItem().findText("Not Applicable") !== null ) {
        childrenToRemove.push(child); 
      }
    }
  }
  
  childrenToRemove.forEach(function(child) {
    try {
      body.removeChild(child);
    }
    catch(e) {
      Logger.log(e)
      if (e == "Exception: Can't remove the last paragraph in a document section.") {
        body.appendPageBreak()
        body.removeChild(child);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

#### References:

- [Class `ListItem` | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/list-item)
- [Enum `ElementType` | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element-type)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help! It works, mostly. The one remaining issue I encountered while using this piece of code is that, in the case where there are more than one bulleted point with the value "Not Applicable", then only the first one will get removed, whilst the remainder is still visible in the document.

Comment: If you remove the `break` line it will continue and remove all bullet points that contain "Not Applicable".

Comment: I had already tried it actually. Even after I removed the 'break' line, it only erases one of the bullet point that contains "Not Applicable" when there are multiple.

Comment: I have updated my code. Without the break this will remove all bullet points that contain 'Not Applicable' in the document, though if the last bullet point is the last paragraph item of the document without a break this will not be able to be removed. I have therefore included a try/catch to remove these also.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the input. I've updated the code with the updated version you wrote here. Now, none of the bullet points with "Not Applicable" is getting removed.

Comment: Can you share an example document for me to take a look at? Of course, sanitise all information from it first.

Comment: Otherwise, check out [my test document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LAh_gDLbQ4k4CwX7v4yKEJZxomHm-61J3tN45HGdaZY/edit?usp=sharing), make a copy and run the script to see if there's some structural difference between our test sheets.

Comment: Here is the link to a partial version of the document: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1862WSRSQUqQCRDeKqspn5Lib7SdoWRZT27YUN3_mBvs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The fields highlighted in yellow are the ones that I have trouble with

Comment: In the test document you just shared, I see that one line with the text "Not Applicable" remains even after playing the script:
"D\f rgf g Not Applicable fagfd"

Comment: Thank you, I think I've got this now. The issue was the child index if two successive bullets contain 'Not Applicable'. I've now separated out obtaining the bullet points and removing them. I have updated my answer.